# Compare dates and then insert data

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have a table like this:

```
Id  UserId  EventTypeId TimeStamp
-----------------------------------------------
344  29        3        2013-01-08 16:28:52.557
350  12        3        2013-01-08 17:06:15.967
441  1         3        2013-01-09 11:00:43.947
461  1         3        2013-01-09 13:29:19.143
```

and the second table:

```
UserId  TimeStamp 
--------------------------------
 1      2014-11-17 10:01:27.443
29      2013-01-05 16:28:52.557
```

In the second table will inserted data if in the first table count of that UserId is more than 20 (beginning from 0 or after new month from second table).

first table is registrations table. Employee registers users and when he/she will reach more than 20 registration he/she will promoted. That promotion dates are and will inserted in that second table.

for example if he/she will register users like this:

```
March: 5 
April: 16 
May: 17
```

After April 30 59:59:59 that time must inserted in second table and after that count must start from scratch.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

What I am understanding is you want to insert record in your second table at the same time when new entry occurs to your first table(Registration). You can achieve this by using insert trigger.
Here, Inserted table contains existing plus new records.

```
    CREATE TRIGGER trig_check_count
    ON [Registration]
    FOR INSERT
    AS
    Begin
     DECLARE @USERID  INT, @COUNT INT
     --FIND USERID FOR INSERTED RECORD
     Select @USERID = I.USERID 
     from Inserted i
     Left Join registration R 
     on R.ID = I.ID AND R.USERID = I.USERID
     where R.ID is null

     --COUNT - START FROM THE PREVIOUS PROMOTION DATE till current date
     SELECT @COUNT = COUNT(I.USERID)
     FROM INSERTED I
     LEFT JOIN PROMOTION P ON I.USERID = P.USERID
     WHERE USERID = @USERID
     AND I.TIMESTAMP > MAX(P.TIMESTAMP)

  -- INSERT TO SECOND TABLE IF COUNT > 20

    IF(@COUNT > 20)
    BEGIN
     INSERT INTO PROMOTION
     SELECT @USERID,GETDATE()
   END

 End
```

Answer (score 0):

Hiren's Trigger is a good idea. i'm just use another way to do this, maybe not good as Hiren XD

```
   select 
     usr.ID,
     usr.USERID,
     usr.EventTypeID,
     usr.TimeStampID,
      COUNT(case when rcd.UserID IS Null then 1 
                 when rcd.UserID IS not null 
                  and rcd.TS< usr.TimeStampID then 1
                  else 0 end)over(partition by UserID) as cnt 
  from table1 usr 
  left join (select UserID,Max(TimeStamp)as TS from table2 group by UserID) rcd 
  on usr.UserID=rcd.UserID
```

here you can see the count of every USERID that TimeStamp are greater then Registration. then you can do the simple math and insert the record into Registration.

```
Insert into regst(UserID,TimeStamp) 
select UserID,TimeStampID from tableabove 
where cnt= 'the number that trigger the insert to table 2'
```